# FreeBSD Inconsistent Ping

Tags: networking, freebsd, local-area-network

I have installed the FreeBSD in a local machine. When I try ping from another Windows PC(Say A) connected in same local network I am getting different output each time.

**1st Ping**

```
Pinging 192.168.1.35 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.35: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.35:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 1, Lost = 3 (75% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

**2nd Ping**

```
Pinging 192.168.1.35 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.35: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.35: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.35:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 2, Lost = 2 (50% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

I tried Pinging another PC(say B) from A. It produces good response(works perfect).

I tried ssh with putty to FreeBSD from A. It connected first time and it was damn slow. after certain time it got disconnected. When I tried 2nd time it didn't connect.

Why this inconsistency is happening and how should i overcome this. I am beginner in UNIX

Comment: Are you definitely sure you haven't another host with the same IP-address in the local network?

Comment: Your problem is probably not on the linux box, but more probably on the network or on the first windows box.

Comment: @Kondybas no it is not assigned to any other pc

Comment: @FrederikNielsen how can i trace it?